# Quick and easy version control for WordPress Themes?

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control

I work alongside two other developers and we seriously need a method of version control implementing within our workflow. Currently we're centralising data using a Synology NAS (which is backing itself up to Google Drive) but the bulk of our development work is done on our local machines just to speed things up.

We've been running into issues lately where we have lost track of file versions when moving between local, centralised and live copies due to our set up. We have suggested, between ourselves, using Git but none of us are experienced with it and after spending today doing some research I feel as though it is not going to actually help. It feels quite clunky and as though it slows the process down. Maybe I'm just doing something wrong?

Anyway, if anybody could suggest a better way/optimal git config they have used or had experience with I would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks in advance,

Ethan.

Comment: @Kirk Beard thanks for the tips :) I'll check those out

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use git, then I suggest to use SVN. You can find a free SVN repository here: https://riouxsvn.com/
Hope it works!

Comment: We don't necessarily want to rule out git - it's more likely a case of inexperience. but, thanks for your suggestion, I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Preparation to use git to version control your WordPress theme:

**1. Remote repo.** This is the place where the versions to be managed and controlled. You can create a remote repo by `git init --bared`. Or you can use github, bitbuckte etc to host your remote repo.

**2. Local repo.** make changes the develop on it. You can use below commands to work with your remote repo:

```
git clone /path/to/remote/repo
git add filename         #after you add/modify a file
git commit -m 'message'  #commit your changes in local repo
git push                 #push your local changes to remote repo
```

More details about git, you can refer [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) .